"Error returned by simulated script: syntax error, RAM exceeded, or other error"
In Block Magic @Chainlink hackaton i cloned the repository:
https://github.com/BunsDev/block-magic-functions-workshop.git
I installed packages and entered my env variables as it is mentioned in readme.
When i want to simulate the contract with "yarn simulate" command i recieve the error:
`root@DESKTOP-IA0TRAI:~/chainlink-functions-test-2/block-magic-functions-workshop# yarn simulate
$ node scripts/Simulate.js
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version
Using Functions request config file /root/chainlink-functions-test-2/block-magic-functions-workshop/request-config.js
error: Module not found "file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1717160603531.ts".
Error returned by simulated script:
syntax error, RAM exceeded, or other error`
This repository seems working as it is published but what can be the origin of this error in my local workspace. I use node "20.12.0" i also tried node 18.

Cannot reproduce your issue. Did you run yarn install before you run the command yarn simulate?

what is file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1717160603531.ts"? Is this your functions script? and perhaps you could share your repo link so we can try and reproduce it?

I resolved the problem by reinstalling Deno.
Because Deno was not able to read the temporare "file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1717160603531.ts" in SimulateScript.js situated in nodes_modules/@chainlink/functions-toolkit/dist/SimulateScript/simulateScript.js.
"file:///tmp/FunctionsScript-1717160603531.ts". If this file with a different number every time is created sussessfully in
const createScriptTempFile = (source) => {
    const tmpDir = os_1.default.tmpdir();
    const sandboxText = fs_1.default.readFileSync(path_1.default.join(__dirname, '/deno-sandbox/sandbox.ts'), 'utf8');
    const script = sandboxText.replace('//INJECT_USER_CODE_HERE', source);
    const tmpFilePath = path_1.default.join(tmpDir, `FunctionsScript-${Date.now()}.ts`);
    fs_1.default.writeFileSync(tmpFilePath, script);
    return tmpFilePath;
};

but not read by Deno in
const simulation = (0, child_process_1.spawn)('deno', [
        'run',
        '--no-prompt',
        `--v8-flags=--max-old-space-size=${maxMemoryUsageMb}`,
        '--allow-net',
        scriptPath,
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(secrets ?? {})).toString('base64'),
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(args ?? {})).toString('base64'),
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(bytesArgs ?? {})).toString('base64'),
        numAllowedQueries.toString(),
        maxQueryDurationMs.toString(),
        maxQueryUrlLength.toString(),
        maxQueryRequestBytes.toString(),
        maxQueryResponseBytes.toString(),
    ]);

That means deno was not correctly installed.
In my case when i enter in the terminale the command "deno", i could have seen the version etc. But the problem disappeared when i reinstalled deno correctly for ubuntu as i use wsl ubuntu. Double check the deno documentation according to your windows or linux set-up.
